# Preview Uploaded Files

Tags: php

I’m currently working on a website that will enable users to upload certain types of files.
Upon the file(s) being uploaded, I need to generate a preview of the file(s) content, in image format.

For example, if somebody was to upload a .doc file containing a letter of some sort (e.g. Absence Letter), then a preview image of the letter needs to be generated.

Some of the files I need to upload and generate a preview of include, but are not limited to: .doc(x), .jpg, .ppt(x), .xls(x), .html, .psd.

Can this be done with PHP?

If not, where would be the best place to start in order to develop this functionality as an extension to PHP?, and what languages could this be done in?

Comment: Maybe you can use the COM interface on Windows systems.

Comment: @user603003 I would like to use Linux if possible. Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe there's already a good library for that which renders for you the document.
Or you could open that file with an application on your linux and make a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my two cents here. This is something no programming language can do inherently. Languages are designed to do something special and do that very well. There might be extensions or additional libraries for certain "common" problems, like PEAR. Mainly because you are dealing here with some proprietary document types (.doc,.ppt,.xls,.psd). First you will need an application able to interpret the source document and by that I mean this application needs a API. Microsoft has VBA for this. Second, this API or another application (it also requires an API) must be able to generate an image of the document, not like a screen shot but a PDF print out. Then there is the big question if or how this APIs are accessible with PHP.

So, I am not saying it cannot be done but there is just no do-it-all language. You have to get and use multiple languages to get your result. PHP I think is still a good solution to tie everything together, though.

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought as much ;) Is it possible and where would you start in making an extension to PHP that allows you to do this?

Comment: I would start with how to get, i.e. programmatically create an image from a word (.doc) document. Look at VBA or maybe there is something with OpenOffice which runs on Linux and is open source. Don't know what you need for .psd docs but implies that you will need more than just one extension. PHP ultimately just needs to save the uploaded document and pass the name to your extensions. Your extensions upon success return the image filename as a result. With that result in PHP you do whatever you want to do with that image and filename.

Comment: I'm kind of after what ZamZar.com does. Only I need it to convert all file types to an image, not to different file formats. How would ZamZar achieve this?

Comment: They achieve this probably exactly like I described it. The problem is not that it cannot be done but more than just one language and an afternoon. I guess they have a bunch of developers. Don't know how many hours they spent on this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use openoffice in that way. This link describes a method to install openoffice, which you can easily call from the commandline and print to pdf.

See:
http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/177241.html

From here you can also convert the first page of this pdf to an image so you can easily preview it.